# Odd "Use of possibly unassigned field 'Type'" - CS0170

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I might be missing something, but I'm getting what I think seems an odd error, that none of the other developers are getting with the same code...

```
public void SomeMethod(... symbolInfo)
{
   ElementId elementId = symbolInfo.GetElementIds().Head(true);
   if (elementId.HasValue())
   {
      // error here "Use of possibly unassigned field 'Type'"
      object element = repository.FindElement(elementId.Type, elementId.Id);
      if (element != null) { ... }
   }
}

public struct ElementId
{
   public string Id;
   public MDAPI_ElementType Type;
}
```

With the following extension methods:

```
public static bool IsEmpty(this ElementId id)
{
    return id.Type == ElementType.ElementUnknown || string.IsNullOrEmpty(id.Id);
}

public static bool HasValue(this ElementId id)
{
   return !id.IsEmpty();
}
```

Can anyone tell my why this won't build?

Comment: How does `symbolInfo.GetElementIds().Head(true)` create the `ElementId`?

Comment: @ChrisF: symbolInfo is a COM object and GetElementIds() is an instance member. I'm not 100% sure on what it does internally. Head attempts to retrieve the first item from an IEnumerable<T> but returns default(T) if it can't find one. Changing .Head(true) to .ToList()[0] gives the same error, so I don't think its the default(T) unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to fix my build error, by instead calling an extension method which directly takes the ElementId. I have no idea why this fixes the issue though!

```
public static object FindElement(this IMRepository rep, ElementId element)
{
    return rep.FindElement(element.Type, element.Id);
}
```

Comment: Even im getting the same kind of error when i used FILETIME. Which basically i needed to limit the CPU usage of my application.